# android How to get width and height of the image blob?

Tags: android, image, height, width, blob

I have stored an Image to Database. I can get the blob but unable to find its correct height and width and hard coding each image width and height is not a good idea. kindly help me out

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice, people will answer when they can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Got the answer from
>
> http://apachejava.blogspot.com/2011/01/get-width-and-height-of-image-blob.html

```
public Bitmap convertBlobToBitmap(byte[] blobByteArray) {       
        Bitmap tempBitmap=null;        
        if(blobByteArray!=null)
        tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blobByteArray, 0, blobByteArray.length);

        return tempBitmap;
    }


Bitmap temp_bitmapImg = convertBlobToBitmap(BitmapArrayOfImage());
                int height = temp_bitmapImg .getHeight();
                int width = temp_bitmapImg .getWidth();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img);
        int WIDTH=bitmap.getWidth();
        int HEIGHT=bitmap.getHeight();
        bitmap.recycle();
```

where `img` will be your image in `drawable`.